# Convert date fromat recieved in XML response while writing to text file using XSLT transformation

Tags: xml, date, xslt, text, format

XML Recieved

```
<ns15:ReferenceEffectiveDate>
                  <ns12:Year>2016</ns12:Year>
                  <ns12:Month>7</ns12:Month>
                  <ns12:Day>20</ns12:Day>
</ns15:ReferenceEffectiveDate>
.
.

.
.
.
.
.
.
<ns15:ReferenceEffectiveDate>
                  <ns12:Year>2016</ns12:Year>
                  <ns12:Month>7</ns12:Month>
                  <ns12:Day>20</ns12:Day>
</ns15:ReferenceEffectiveDate>
```

This is the type of date recieved in my response XML from a web service.

I have been recieving the date format as YYYYMD when month and day are single digit. and YYYYMMDD when months and day are double digits.

I want to get the format as YYYYMMDD always using the XSLT transformation.

Currently i am pulling using

```
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:for-each select......(sometext which cannot be written)>
<xsl:value-of select="ns2:ReferenceEffectiveDate"/>
<xsl:value-of select="$line-separator"/>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

please help how can i get the format fixed.

Current output recieved looks like

```
2016630
2016630
2016630
2016630
2016630
2016630
2016630
```

Desired output is

```
20160630
20160630
20160630
20160630
20160630
```

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to answer your question exactly, because the context is missing, In general, you need to do something like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="ns15:ReferenceEffectiveDate">
    <xsl:value-of select="ns12:Year"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(ns12:Month, '00')"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number(ns12:Day, '00')"/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Its Giving output as 

    NaNNaN
    NaNNaN
    NaNNaN
    NaNNaN

Comment: That's possible, because you did not post a [mcve] and I had to guess some parts. But the principle is correct - see it working here: http://xsltransform.net/94AbWAz